# Why was the Republic so interested in Naboo?

Tags: star-wars

I don't understand why the Republic was so interested in the planet Naboo; it's a small planet in a big Galaxy.
Queen Amidala didn't agree with the taxation of trade routes to outlying star systems, it's clear, but the Republic wants to have access to these planets uncontended. Why is Naboo so important to the development of the Republic?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question so that it is an answerable one - what makes you think the Republic was especially interested in Naboo? It obviously features heavily in the movies, but there is nothing I can think of that suggests Naboo is treated differently from any other planet by the Republic.

Comment: I think the better question would be "Why was the Trade Federation so interested in Naboo?"

Comment: Are you asking why the Republic sent Jedi to help negotiate with the Trade Federation?

Comment: @CBredlow I think he's wondering why Naboo was so important as to risk war. Hopefully he can clear that up.

Comment: The book "Darth Plagueis" has lots of info about this, I'll see if I can remember some of it.

Comment: Speculation- Many in the Republic were likely angered by the Trade Federation invading a planet of pacifists (at least its human population) that posed little, if any threat- like how IRL when Mussolini ordered an invasion of Ethiopia or Saddam ordered an attack on Kuwait. They saw someone kicking the underdog and got upset.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you have it flipped around. It was the Trade Federation that was protesting the taxation of trade routes by the Republic. Thus they blockaded Naboo, which would in turn cause that planets senator to plead to the senate to repeal the taxation.  Naboo was selected because Darth Sidious wanted Palpatine to protest and call out the corruption in the senate.

Comment: Palpatine is Sidious. He selected the planet because he can much more easily control the situation if it's his own home that he represents...

Comment: @Derek dude, spoilers! :P

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I didn't know why the viceroy attacked Naboo.

Comment: @CBredlow Derek is doing everyone a favor by spoiling Ep1 - now they don't have to waste their time watching it.

Comment: @Derek so palpatine was born and raised in Naboo?

Comment: Without anything else from the movies to go on, yes.